# Replace sequence using regexpression C#

Tags: c#, regex

I try to replace every occurrence of "parent" delimited with dots (at both sides) on some string (say "blah"). I.e. for string

```
$view.parent.parent.data.CurrentCategoryId, $view.parent.parent.data.CurrentFolderId
```

I need string

```
$view.blah.blah.data.CurrentCategoryId, $view.blah.blah.data.CurrentFolderId
```

I try to do this with code

```
content = Regex.Replace(content,
                                        "(?<preSymbol>[\\.^\"'])" + "parent" +
                                        "(?<postSymbol>[\\.$\"'])",
                                        m =>
                                        m.Groups["preSymbol"] + "blah" +
                                        m.Groups["postSymbol"]);
```

but get

```
view.blah.parent.data.CurrentCategoryId, $view.blah.parent.data.CurrentFolderId
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is that capture groups are preventing you from replacing all instances of `parent` because matches cannot overlap.

What you can do however is to use zero width matches, i.e. those that don't count towards matches, and for that you need lookarounds. Try:

```
"(?<=[\\.^\"'])" + "parent" +
"(?=[\\.$\"'])",
```

`(?<= ... )` is a positive lookbehind, which makes sure there's what inside before the pattern,

`(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead, which makes sure there's what inside after the pattern.

Neither counts towards matches.

However, your interpretation of the pattern is not completely correct. Both `^` and `$` lose their functionality in character classes. You should use:

```
"(?<=[\\.\"']|^)" + "parent" +
"(?=[\\.\"']|$)",
```

Instead to mean beginning and end of the string. Now, you don't need to escape periods in character classes:

```
"(?<=[.\"']|^)" + "parent" +
"(?=[.\"']|$)",
```

Also, your replace can be simply `blah` now, since no other characters other than `parent` were matched.